# Iam trying to run my nextjs application , but getting an error TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: next.js

Iam trying to run my nextjs application , but getting an error TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

```html
API_BASE_URL='http://localhost:3000'

export function getStrapiURL(path = "") {
  return `${process.env.API_BASE_URL}${path}`;
}


export async function fetchAPI(path) {
  const requestUrl = getStrapiURL(path);
  const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you will have to use an absolute URL for the `fetch` you're making. I'm assuming it has something to do with the different environments (client & server) on which your code can be executed. Relative URLs are just not explicit & reliable enough in this case.

One way to solve this would be to just hardcode the server address into your `fetch` request, another to set up a `config` module that reacts to your environment:

**config/index.js**

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export const API_BASE_URL = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://your_deployment.server.com';
```